# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.04.03 Server in VMware Workstation 10

Tags: server, vmware

When I try to install Ubuntu following the It doesn't work. 
It starts normally asking for a language, then when I click on "Install Ubuntu server"
my screen goes black and nothing happens. It never goes to the select your location and install language.

Same issue happens with 386 or amd64 version

[I follow this guide normally with success](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/step-by-step-ubuntu-12-04-precise-lamp-server-setup.html) but not this time!

Any idea??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Its seeems to be related to my BIOS. I did an update of it. And then Iw as able to
perform the installation without any other issue!

Nothing else was changed! Just the Bios update!

I now have Ubuntu running in a VM.

Thanks to all.